# 'Permission denied' issue even after granting

Tags: flutter, permission-denied, samsung-galaxy

'Permission denied' issue even after granting. Issue is only with Samsung galaxy devices. I am using galaxy A14.

Android Manifest File:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

[see screenshot of app setting here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xYUD.jpg)

here I cant see any storage permission to allow from settings.
when I printed the storage permission status it show denied.

Answer (score 1):

try adding these permissions too

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
```

update

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_STORAGE"/>
```

then check then version and handle accordingly

```
Future<void> _getStoragePermission() async {
    DeviceInfoPlugin plugin = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    AndroidDeviceInfo android = await plugin.androidInfo;
       if (android.version.sdkInt < 33) {
          if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
             setState(() {
               permissionGranted = true;
             });
          } else if (await Permission.storage.request().isPermanentlyDenied) {
             await openAppSettings();
          } else if (await Permission.audio.request().isDenied) {
             setState(() {
               permissionGranted = false;
             });
          }
        } else {
           if (await Permission.photos.request().isGranted) {
                setState(() {
                   permissionGranted = true;
                });
           } else if (await Permission.photos.request().isPermanentlyDenied) {
               await openAppSettings();
           } else if (await Permission.photos.request().isDenied) {
               setState(() {
                   permissionGranted = false;
               });
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. 
Your solution opens the app settings, but I can't see storage permission.

I just described my issue in detail by editing it, can you please check it.

Comment: have added two more permission @MaheshBorse just check with that too and let me know

Comment: I have tried your updated solution but it does not fixed this issue.
I have tried other Samsung galaxy devices having no problem with theme.